# If statement for scoring system in 'catch the egg' game not calling

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game where the point of it is that you have to catch the falling 'eggs' in your basket, and the sensitivity of the paddle gradually goes up, making it harder and harder, and I'm coding in the if statement that checks if the egg went into the basket, but it's not working. I've tried quite a bit, and the if statement runs when the 'egg' gets to the bottom of the screen, checking if it is between the edges of the paddle. My code is here.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("ok");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var loggingMachine = document.getElementById("loggy");
var score = 0;
const Rg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
function ball(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 0;
  this.width = 20;
  this.height = 20;
}
var firstBall = new ball(Rg);
function newBall() {
  if (firstBall.y < 480) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 480);
    ctx.fillRect(firstBall.x, firstBall.y, firstBall.width, firstBall.height);
    firstBall.y++;
  } else {
    if (
      firstBall.x - 10 > player.x &&
      firstBall.x - 10 < player.x - player.width
    ) {
      alert("yawwo");
    }
    firstBall.y = 0;
    firstBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
  }
}
function paddle(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 470;
  this.width = 70;
  this.height = 20;
}

var player = new paddle(50);
function renderPlayer() {
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

  function logKey(e) {
    if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
      player.x = player.x - 0.01;
    } else if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
      player.x = player.x + 0.01;
    }
    loggingMachine.innerText = score;
  }
}

function tick() {
  newBall(Rg);
  renderPlayer();
  setTimeout(tick, 5);
}
tick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<canvas id="ok" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
<p id="loggy"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: your collision detection needed a little fine polishing.

See the Example below.

Happy Coding

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("ok");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var loggingMachine = document.getElementById("loggy");
var score = 0;
const Rg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
function ball(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 0;
  this.width = 20;
  this.height = 20;
}
var firstBall = new ball(Rg);
function newBall() {
  if (firstBall.y < 480) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 480);
    ctx.fillRect(firstBall.x, firstBall.y, firstBall.width, firstBall.height);
    firstBall.y++;
  } else {
  
  const playerStart = player.x;
  const playerEnd = player.x + player.width;
  
  const ballStart = firstBall.x;
  const ballEnd = firstBall.x + firstBall.width;
  
  const test1 = ballEnd - playerStart;
  const test2 = ballStart - playerEnd;
  
    if (
      test1 >= 0 && test2 <= 0
    ) {
      score++;
    }
    firstBall.y = 0;
    firstBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
  }
}
function paddle(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 470;
  this.width = 70;
  this.height = 20;
}

var player = new paddle(50);

function logKey(e) {
  if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    player.x = player.x - 15;
            
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
      player.x = player.x + 15;
  }
  
}  
document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

function renderPlayer() {
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  loggingMachine.innerText = score;
}

function tick() {
  newBall(Rg);
  renderPlayer();
  setTimeout(tick, 5);
}
tick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<canvas id="ok" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
<p id="loggy"></p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you know why the paddle continues moving faster and faster?

Comment: Yes, the reason was that `document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey)` was inside of `renderPlayer` and so a new keydown listerner was added every  milliseconds. I adjusted the example, now you have a constant speed of the paddle and the score does update right after the collision. - Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions wasn't right, because you need to check if ball's position is between pad's position, so:

```
    if (
      // Add 10 to ensure at least half the ball is touching left edge of the pad
      firstBall.x + 10 > player.x &&
      // Subtract 10 to ensure at least half the ball is touching right edge of the pad
      // Add width to the pad's position to calculate its right edge
      firstBall.x - 10 < player.x + player.width
    ) {
      alert("yawwo");
      // Increment score and update on screen
      score ++;
      loggingMachine.innerText = score;
    }
    firstBall.y = 0;
    firstBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("ok");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var loggingMachine = document.getElementById("loggy");
var score = 0;
const Rg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
function ball(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 0;
  this.width = 20;
  this.height = 20;
}
var firstBall = new ball(Rg);
function newBall() {
  if (firstBall.y < 480) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 480, 480);
    ctx.fillRect(firstBall.x, firstBall.y, firstBall.width, firstBall.height);
    firstBall.y++;
  } else {
    if (
      firstBall.x + 10 > player.x &&
      firstBall.x - 10 < player.x + player.width
    ) {
      alert("yawwo");
      score ++;
      loggingMachine.innerText = score;
    }
    firstBall.y = 0;
    firstBall.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 480);
  }
}
function paddle(x) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = 470;
  this.width = 70;
  this.height = 20;
}

var player = new paddle(50);
function renderPlayer() {
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

  function logKey(e) {
    if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
      player.x = player.x - 0.01;
    } else if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
      player.x = player.x + 0.01;
    }
  }
}

function tick() {
  newBall(Rg);
  renderPlayer();
  setTimeout(tick, 5);
}
tick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<canvas id="ok" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
<p id="loggy">0</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```